# Mozilla, not rendering RichFaces component

Tags: richfaces

I have problem with RichFaces 4. Mozilla web browser not rendering Rich UI components.

In build path i have jar:

- richfaces-core-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.3.7.Final.jar
- richfaces-components-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
- richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar
- guava.jar
- cssparser-0.9.14.jar
- sac-1.3.jar

Web browser not rendering event simple xhtml page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>

<rich:panel>
    <a4j:commandButton value = "Button"></a4j:commandButton>
</rich:panel>

  </h:body>
</html>
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Check war contents if {richfaces-...} jars in \WEB-INF\lib\ folder. Probably those jars not checked for export in "Order and Export" tab of "Java Build Path".

Comment: I checked all jars in "Order and Export" but sill mozilla not render ui components. I trying create maven projects but tis is also not working.

Comment: What do you see on the page? What's in the source code? Not rendering is rather vague.